# Ajax call posting duplicates in DB

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I am using to Fullcalendar jquery with php for event management. I using ajax call for adding events. The call works fine for the first event entry after refresh. But for the following event entries duplicate events are created for each entry. Not sure what causing this.

This is the error:

[image]

This is the jquery call:

**Jquery**

```
$('#evesav').bind('click',function(){

   $('#evesav').attr('disabled','disabled');
   var title = $('#evename').val();
   var edes = $('#evedes').val();
   var everegion = $('#everegion').val();
   var eveserv = $('#eveserv').val();

   $.ajax({
   url: 'add_events.php',
   data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&edes='+ edes +'&everegion='+     everegion +'&eveserv='+ eveserv,
   type: "POST",
   success: function(json) {
   $('#myModal').modal('hide');
   $('#alertcon').html(json);
   $('#alert').modal('show');      
   $('#evename').val("");
   $('#evedes').val("");
   $('#evesav').removeAttr('disabled');
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );

   }
   });


   $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' );

   });
```

This is the PHP Code:

**PHP**

```
 <?php

    if(($_POST['title'] && $_POST['start'] && $_POST['end'] && $_POST['edes'] &&           $_POST['everegion'] && $_POST['eveserv'])!= NULL)
    {
    // Values received via ajax
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $start = $_POST['start'];
    $end = $_POST['end'];
    $edes = $_POST['edes'];
    $region = $_POST['everegion'];
    $server = $_POST['eveserv'];
    //echo $title."".$start."".$end."".$edes."".$region."".$server;
    // connection to the database
    include('includes/db.php');


    // insert the records
    $sql = "INSERT INTO evenement (title, start, end, edes, region, server) VALUES (:title, :start, :end, :edes, :region, :server)";
    $q = $bdd->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array(':title'=>$title, ':start'=>$start, ':end'=>$end, ':edes'=>$edes, ':region'=>$region, ':server'=>$server));
    if($q->execute(array(':title'=>$title, ':start'=>$start, ':end'=>$end, ':edes'=>$edes, ':region'=>$region, ':server'=>$server))){
var_dump($q->execute(array(':title'=>$title, ':start'=>$start, ':end'=>$end, ':edes'=>$edes, ':region'=>$region, ':server'=>$server)));
    }
    $eveid=$bdd->lastInsertId(); 


    // Get array of all source files
   $files = scandir("uploads/");
   // Identify directories
   $source = "uploads/";
   $destination = "evedata/".$eveid."/";
   mkdir("evedata/".$eveid);
   // Cycle through all source files
   foreach ($files as $file) {
   if (in_array($file, array(".",".."))) continue;
   // If we copied this successfully, mark it for deletion
   if (copy($source.$file, $destination.$file)) {
   $delete[] = $source.$file;
   }
   }
   // Delete all successfully-copied files
   foreach ($delete as $file) {
       unlink($file);
       }


       echo "Added Successfully";
       }
  else {
echo "Please Fill the data";
    }
    ?>
```

Some one please help me with this.

Comment: Before Insert query you should check whether event is already inserted  for a particular star an end

Comment: Check your developer console. Check the network tab and see if the data is actually sent more than once (or not). This will help determine if it's the client side code or something else.

Comment: you have to unbind the click action, or it stays in the dom. `$('#evesav').unbind("click");`   i'm not sure if that's true but i had a similar problem once an read a similar answer on stack overflow. just google "duplicate ajax submission"

Comment: @r3wt tried that didn't help

Comment: @Undefined_variable the start and end also duplicates in other dates too. sometimes

Comment: @LeeTaylor checked it the jquery is the one that throws multiple calls

Comment: What is `evesav` ? submit button?

Comment: @winnyboy5 Is Your code is submitting all the events when a new entry is made i.e let's say on 10 a is added and then b is added for 11? In this case you will have to check whether the event for start and end is already there an similar to on submitted by Ajax

Comment: @LeeTaylor Just a form button without submit attribute

Comment: @Undefined_variable tried your idea it worked. Thanks man Post it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd give each event addition form a control, for instance a dynamic GUID, which then can be used to save to DB. This way you have a GUID to work with in dealing with CalDAV protocol, if you ever choose to do as such with your calendar, as well as have a way to make certain nothing is duplicated by chance in your database.

Now, do keep in mind this is simply a patch, not a fix. Therefore, you'll do yourself a lot of good to find a way to stop the multiple attempts to add an event to your DB. Regardless of your success in finding your bug, using a control mechanism or unique identifier is a good idea.